# any other option to verify our free tier account on Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Foundations,

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm encountering a challenge with verifying my free tier account on Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Foundations. As I'm living in Ethiopia, international credit cards are not accessible in my country, and I've exhausted the three available options. I'm reaching out to seek advice and explore if there are any alternative methods or suggestions for verifying the account. Any assistance or ideas from the community would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your support!